# Fetching data to webpage using angular HTTP in spring

Tags: angularjs, rest

```
<table>
<th>
<tr>.........</tr>
</th>
</table>
```

I want to display data from MySQL DB into the above `<tr>.....</tr>` with help of angular in a spring project.

What could be the easy way to do it?

Comment: what do you want to say exactly ??:D

Comment: @ Kishore Kumar Naidu angular

Comment: use `$http` and you can use `ng-repeat` attribute at your `tr` and in the `td/s` you can bind the data with `{{yourdata}}`, remember to return `json` from the backend.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you this:

In your view:

```
 <table ng-controller="MyCtrl"> <!--your ctrl-->
   <tr ng-repeat="item in items"><!--place the ng-repeat-->
     <td>{{item.name}}</td> <!--bind the data-->
   </tr>
 </table>
```

in your controller:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []); // most important to define angular module

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $http) { // controller def
  $http.get('data.json').
    success(function(data) { // ajax
       $scope.items = data; // update the items var in $scope here
    });
});
```

`data.json` will be the url from which you will get your data to display in the table. Take a look at the demo plunkr added.

#### [Plunkr Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/9dvHk4WxnO85xWPiPDFd?p=preview)

Comment: suppose i have a table named as user in MySQL which have all the usernames ,i want to display these usernames in my table. how will i get those user.json from MySQL please guide me.or will it fetch automatically json when i give user.json in HTTP argument .

Comment: @surendrakumar see the demo i have added it is just that which you are asking but the thing is you have to return usernames in the json like `[{"username":"user1"....}]`, so it depends on you to generate the json from the backend.

Comment: See you need to use GSON jars to convert your arraylists to json objects and you just need to return that and you just need to replace the `data.json` with your method url.

Comment: yes i want to know exactly how do i generate json from backend

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Array-Examples this will help you.

Comment: can you give me a code for what you said now,to convert arraylists to json objects and  return that